# How to add the Ajax Control Toolkit to Visual Web Developer Express 2008

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

Anybody knows where to copy the AjaxControlToolkit.DLL so that it appears in the Toolbox under Ajax controls? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/02/07/ajax-control-tookit-installation-in-visual-web-developer.aspx